# nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20' while cuda 9.1+caffe+openCV 3.4.0 is installed

Tags: opencv, cmake, cuda, caffe, cudnn

I have installed `CUDA 9.1+cudnn-9.1+opencv 3.4.0+caffe`.

When I tried to run `make all -j8` in `caffe` directory, this error occurred:

> nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20'

I have tried to run:

`"cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler .."`

but it didn't work.

Comment: CUDA 9.x +  does not support compute_20 (Fermi), probably you will have to disable it, maybe with `ccmake` you can disable it manually? not sure which variable in your project is the one that is setting this, but probably you will see several numbers like 2.0, 3.0, etc. You just need to delete 2.0

Comment: That's correct.  CUDA 9.1 does not support `compute_20` anymore.  You'll need to find a makefile that doesn't call out that architecture, or else edit the makefile (or CMakeLists.txt)  to remove references to `compute_20` or `sm_20`.  Or you could switch to CUDA 8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try manually edit [`Makefile.config`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example#L33-L38) to remove `compute_2*` architectures from these lines (comments explain why):

```
# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61
```

And add the compute_6* architectures (see the comments) so that your new CUDA_ARCH looks like this:

```
# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61
```

Then you'll need to `make clean` before `make all`.

Answer (score 2):

Makefile.config is not used when compilation is done with cmake. Therefore removing compute_2* architectures from it doesn't solve the problem. Instead, you should edit caffe/Cuda.cmake. On line 9 just get rid of 20 21(20) on the list of known GPU architectures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cmake like following:

```
cmake [other_params] -D CUDA_ARCH_NAME="Pascal" ..
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me

```
cd caffe && mkdir build && cd build && \
   cmake -DUSE_CUDNN=1 -DUSE_NCCL=1 -DCUDA_ARCH_NAME=Manual -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="50 52 60 61" .. && \
   sudo make -j"$(nproc)"
```

Just dropped `20` and `30` arch support